# Set locale before first login

Tags: debian, system-installation, login, locale

I am preparing virtual machine drive image with preinstalled Debian and some additional software. This image would be used by people speaking different languages and even using different keyboard layouts. This introduces some problems during first login when a password is requested. It would be perfect if the user would be asked to set proper language/keyboard layout during first boot (locales can be preinstalled) just before the graphical login screen. With this customisation my solution would be much more multilingual user friendly. How to achieve this? Maybe it is possible to execute somehow script that is used during the installation of Debian?

Comment: Which login manager are you going to use? lightdm, gdm, ...?

Comment: I use default one, so it is gdm.

Answer (score 1):

`gdm` removed that option, but `lightdm` still has it.

You need to install these two packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

`lightdm` has the concept of indicators, shown at login time. They are specified in the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter`. Add a this to the end:

```
indicators=~language
```

Restart the login manager and you will have the option to set the language (from the list your installed locales).

If you want to also be able to choose the keyboard layout you should add instead:

```
indicators=~language;~layout
```

But those modifications will list only the specified indicators. If you want to make it look a bit more like the default, you could add the missing ones:

```
indicators=~host;~spacer;~language;~layout;~session;~language;~layout;~a11y;~clock;~power
```

There are comments with more information related to indicators in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter`.

`xfce4` will pick up the chosen locale, but for Gnome `LANG` (could be `LANGUAGE`) in `/etc/default/locale` supersedes that value. The solution is to not define it there (either remove or comment out the line).

Comment: Fixed, thanks@Cob!

Comment: After this procedure I have language options in the right upper corner during the login. However, then gnome is launched and there is still everything in English even when French locale was selected.

Comment: Try it again. Now I remember that the same happened to me the first time and then it worked for all users.

Comment: Unfortunately gnome still starts in English. Moreover, during login I can choose different keyboard layout from installed ones, but after reboot last selection is not persisted and it only affects login screen. Keyboard layout is immediatelly changed but only in login screen. I can also choose language, but list contains probably all possible languages. After login gnome always starts in English with us keyboard layout. I can change layout on its top bar, but I hoped it to be the same as in login screen.

Comment: Is the French locale installed? You could do `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to make sure it is correctly built ... My versions: Debian 10, lightdm-gtk-greeter 2.0.6-1, lightdm 1.26.0-4. I switch with no problems between French, Esperanto, Spanish and Chinese. But my session manager is xfce4.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it. xfce4 works, but Gnome uses `/etc/default/locale`. I commented out the LANG variable that file and now also the Gnome session uses the language I choose at login. Does it work for you? If it does, I will update the answer.

Comment: French locale is installed. Commented LANG in /etc/default/locale makes no change. Gnome always starts with en.

Comment: I noticed that after commenting also LANGUAGE variable in that file I have such behavior: changing of locale in session manager (not language) makes change in gnome, but change of language (not locale) and rather after second login. Very strange.